# How to transform a tuple into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I need help with a list of tuples.

I have the next list:

```
list = [('x1', '10'), ('x2', '15'), ('x3', '35'), ('x4', '55')]
```

I need to transform a tuple into a dictionary and get the next result:

```
list = [{'name':'x1', 'amount':'10'}, {'name':'x2', 'amount':'15'}, 
        {'name':'x3', 'amount':'35'}, {'name':'x4', 'amount':'55'}]
```

Comment: `your_results = [{'name':t[0], 'amount':t[1]} for t in your_list]`

Answer (score 1):

You also use `dict()` constructor inside a list comprehension:

```
out = [dict(zip(['name','amount'], tpl)) for tpl in lst]
```

or equivalently, you can also use `dict()` constructor inside `map`:

```
out = list(map(lambda tpl: dict(zip(['name','amount'], tpl)), lst))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'x1', 'amount': '10'},
 {'name': 'x2', 'amount': '15'},
 {'name': 'x3', 'amount': '35'},
 {'name': 'x4', 'amount': '55'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a nested dictionary comprehension.

```py
list_of_tuples = [('x1', '10'), ('x2', '15'), ('x3', '35'), ('x4', '55')]
result = [{'name': name, 'amount': amount} for name, amount in list_of_tuples]
```

This is equivalent to the more verbose (but perhaps more readable)

```py
result = []
for name, amount in list_of_tuples:
    d = {'name': name, 'amount': amount}
    result.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```py
list = [('x1', '10'), ('x2', '15'), ('x3', '35'), ('x4', '55')]
dic={}
list2=[]
for i in range(len(list)): 
    dic2={}
    dic2['name']=list[i][0]
    dic2['amount']=list[i][1]
    list2.append(dic2)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Your code is not running, could you double chek it and edit it please?

Comment: i forget to add the initialization of list variable check it now but i tested it into my laptop and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [('x1', '10'), ('x2', '15'), ('x3', '35'), ('x4', '55')]

_list = []
for i in list:
    _list.append({"name":i[0],"amount":i[1]})

print(_list)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?